# Another RoboCopy File / Folder Migration Q

Tags: file, migration, share, robocopy

Hi Sorry to ask another question regarding robocopy but by its very nature it is quite diverse so I need to be clear on what I am trying to achieve.

Scenario.

Moving from a Nas to a windows file Share , Completely New ACL's will be created and inherited from the new share already setup . SO this is a straight file and folder copy with mirroring.

I decided to use powershell to run the command - it felt right at the time and achieved the desired result on a few shares .

I mapped the drive and ran the following .

```
robocopy z:\"Dept Folder 1"\ E:\Shares\deptdata\"New dept folder" /e /LOG+:file /v /TEE
robocopy z:\"Dept Folder 2"\ E:\Shares\deptdata\"New dept folder2" /e /LOG+:file /v /TEE
```

The files and folders copied as expected inheriting the new ACL's The first Job finished and then moved on to the second copy and again completed successfully.

What I would like to do now on some of the larger shares is incorporate the mir command as I need to keep a constant mirror on all folders until such time as I have tested the new ACL's and I have mapped the new drive via GPO.

My First Question knowing the behaviour when having batched commands is this .

When using the Mir command will the first command in the batch continue to mirror 
the share and move onto the next Mirror command and so forth. or will it just sit their mirroring the first command and not move onto the second?

If it wont move on to the next command how do I achieve that is it possible? would i have to run multiple mirror commands at the same time and not batch them up in one?

When the Mir command is running if I add new files into the New destination will those files get deleted, or is it only mirroring the source and doesn't care about new files in the destination?

Where would I specify the MIR command?

Comment: HI All , just an update to this as I have done some testing - and I am thinking of 
 a workaround that perhaps someone with some powershell knowledge might be able to help with to create a loop.
I ran the command
robocopy z:\"Dept Folder 1"\ E:\Shares\deptdata\"New dept folder"  /mir /e /LOG+:file /v /TEE 
This ran through each command  as desired but it didn't continually mirror it just ended and moved onto the next .I then added /MON:2 onto the end and it continually waited checking the share for changes but would not move onto the next command .

Comment: Is there a PS Command that will go back to the first command until I tell it to stop ? I think that will continually mirror the share as I intend . Any problems with doing this ?